# Which all packages' versions should I be checking in order to avoid merge conflicts in pubspec.lock file while developing flutter apps

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, merge-conflict-resolution

As I am working on a group project using flutter and Android Studio I have been getting errors in the pubspec.lock file after merging.What are the ways in which I could avoid that and what precautions should I be taking in order to reduce such errors?Which all packages' version should I be checking (We were advised to use the latest versions)?

Answer (score 1):

when you merge a Project you should delete the old pubspeck.lock file

Delete pubspec.lock file go to **pubspec.yaml** file and

run

flutter pub get

in your terminal